# PowerShell: Use One of Multiple Values from an Output

Tags: powershell, ip, command-line-interface

I was able to get the IP addresses of the DNS servers configured for my computer using the ff:

```
$DNSServers = Get-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet" | select -expand ServerAddresses
```

The output contained two distinct IP address values.  How can I extract and use one of those values as the value for a variable to be used for an LDAP query in AD?

For example, if the output for the above code is `192.168.10.101 172.16.100.201`, I should be able to pass either of those IP address values to the variable for the code for my LDAP query.

Comment: Try `$DNSServers[0]`,`$DNSServers[1]` etc

Comment: Wow! So it was really that simple, then. Just what was needed =)  But, @mjsqu, you gave the answer on a comment.  There's no option to mark it as the answer I was looking for. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Answer your own question based on mjsqu's comment

Comment: what about the point(s)?

Comment: Thanks for your recognition, I've now included an answer which goes into a bit more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the concise explanation that went with it. Could now do more with the arrays that I would get from other commands. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Ascertaining the data type

The command you've written returns an array. You can see this by passing it to `Out-GridView`:

```
$DNSServers | Out-GridView
```

or checking the type:

```
$DNSServers.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

### Accessing data

Arrays can be accessed by index:

```
$DNSServers[0]
$DNSServers[1]
etc...
```

It's important to note that the array indexing starts at zero, not 1.

#### For Each loop

In a loop:

```
ForEach ($server in $DNSServers) {
    # Do something with server
    $server
}
```

#### For loop with iteration

Or by index in a loop, using the Array's `Count` property:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $DNSServers.Count; $i++)
{ 
    $DNSServers[$i]
}
```

#### Piping

You can also pipe the object into a For Each, the shorthand notation for this is `%`. Each element in the loop is assigned the internal variable `$_`:

```
$DNSServers | % {
    # Do something with server ($_)
    $_
}
```

This is not as readable, but handy if you're just writing a quick script for one-off use.

Tip: If you hit Ctrl+J in Powershell ISE, you'll bring up the snippets menu, which contains prebuilt `for` loop syntax, of both types specified here. However, be careful, as the `for` snippet starts at `$i = 1`, so you need to change it when using it with arrays.